# Refreshing sandbox deletes/removes users

Tags: sandbox, refresh

I have a full copy sandbox where we are going to load around 5000 users. We are going to test our bulk load of accounts, contacts and custom object records in that sandbox. Once we are done with our Full Functional and Data Testing, we will delete the objects records.

However, we cannot delete users, we can only inactivate them. So, if I do Production refresh, is there a way these 5000 users will go away and only the users available in Production will arrive in the full copy sandbox?

Answer (score 9):

When you do a refresh of the full copy sandbox, all data (including users) will be overwritten.

So the 5000 users you've loaded into Sandbox will be wiped out once you refresh from Production, unless you load them into Production first.